# regex to filter out youtube videos in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field and want to check using regex if the field name has youtube inside it.

```
<input name="videoUrl" ng-pattern="youtubeRegex" required ng-model="video.url" type="text" class="form-control" id="video-link" placeholder="Enter video link from youtube">
<p ng-show="videoForm.videoUrl.$invalid && !videoForm.videoUrl.$pristine">
                                  the link has to be from youtube
                                </p>
```

and in the controller I have

```
$scope.youtubeRegex= 'youtube';
```

However when I start typing the errors shows immediately and even if I paste a link from youtube it still validates it as wrong.

Comment: How are you validating the youtube url please share you code???

Comment: I am using the ng-pattern directive

Comment: Are you able to use ng-messages for this?

Comment: use  $scope.youtubeRegex = https://www.youtube.com; instead of $scope.youtubeRegex= youtube;

Comment: what is the difference ? I always have the "www" infront as well so why should I add .com but not www. ?

Comment: not .com you have to add the url with "http://"
https://plnkr.co/edit/UTfVxoNw0E3vWSVdeNkq?p=preview check this plunker

Comment: This wont work since I want to filter out any links that are not from youtube and your code accepts any links ( both from youtube and not ). Thank you for the "type:url" hint though :)

Comment: Is your problem ok with type:url????

Comment: Not really. Because "type:url" makes sure I input an URL but does not care if this URL is from youtube or not  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
$scope.youtubeRegex= /youtube/;
```

Here's a Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4Y3RkPccKxxoSQJFf2Zj?p=preview

This will allow you to paste correctly. As far as seeing errors from the get go this is expected behavior since it's technically incorrect as you type. To avoid this you would want to run the error message show when the user is done typing.

This can obviously be done with a submit button but also with [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur#!) to determine when the user is done typing and then run a function that checks the validity state of your form and shows/hides a note. Along the same lines you can also use [ngModeloptions.debounce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#!).

The concept is the same - check the form validity and show/hide the error element.

Comment: Hey, I know it does not make any sense but having "/youtube/" as regex does not fix the problem that it considers valid URLs as invalid

Comment: Can you update your code to show the modification as well as paste the sample URL that is not working?